# IE is acting inconsistently with a jQuery change/ajax event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am working on a fairly simple demo app.  Three input dropdown boxes are displayed using `slideDown()` in succession (this fires on a `change()` of the previous dropdown), and one uses an AJAX request to determine the next one's values.

This works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox, but IE (even 9) chokes on the second dropdown- the one that executes the AJAX request.

Because code speaks louder than words:

```
$('#specialty').change(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() !== "(please select an option)" ) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getValidToppings.php",
                data: { location: $(this).parent().prev().children('select').val() }
        }).done(function(data) {
            var mytoppings, toppingsSelectBox;

            console.log('return values: ' + data);

            data = $.parseJSON(data);

            toppingsSelectBox = $('#toppings');
            toppingsSelectBox.empty();

            // we use the value from the select box as a key in the dict of toppings returned
            // from the AJAX call
            mytoppings = data[$('#specialty').val()];

            toppingsSelectBox.append('<option>(please select an option)</option>')

            for (i in mytoppings) {
                toppingsSelectBox.append("<option>"+mytoppings[i]+"</option>");
            }

            toppingsSelectBox.parent().slideDown('slow', 'linear');
        });
    }
});
```

You can see that when I change this dropdown (where `id="specialty"`), the values returned via AJAX (in JSON) are supposed to fill up the `.toppings` input, and then reveal it (with `slideDown()`).  But, in IE... no dice.

What's REALLY WEIRD is, if I boot up IE's dev tools and start tinkering with Javascript (set breakpoint, use console, etc.), it starts working as anticipated.  Even if I only OPEN dev tools, as soon as that window is open it starts working.  What the heck?

Something weird is happening here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't know what "console" is, except when you have the dev tools open. Take out the `console.log` and you should be good. Also make sure you aren't missing any semicolons, IE tends to not like that.

Comment: Oi!  IE is so temperamental.  I'd been watching semicolons like a hawk, but taking out console.log worked like a charm.  Never even would have thought of that.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, you could use `dataType:'json'` in the $.ajax call so you don't have to manually parse it. And while I'm at it, why don't you use a value (-1) for your default entry? then you wouldn't have to compare with a string which could change

Comment: About the semicolons: Facebox (jquery lightbox) is coded entirely without semicolons and works fine even in IE6. You just have to be careful :D

Comment: Yeah, I've just had issues before so I thought I'd mention it. @ZenLikeThat if you could mark as answer that'd be great.

Comment: @Thomas dataType: 'json' would be great, thanks for that.  And I'm not sure how I would make (-1) my default entry, as the point of the string is so that it is displayed that way to users.  Care to elaborate?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I'm waiting for my "accept an answer" time window to be up.  I wouldn't deny you the sweet, sweet, internet points :)